# Peculiar icon specification in .desktop file

Tags: wine, icons, .desktop

I have installed a Windows program (Evernote) on my Ubuntu 13.04 system using Wine. During installation a desktop shortcut was created containing (among others) this line:

```
Icon=63EC_Evernote.0
```

This results in the Evernote logo icon being displayed, which is fine.

But I wonder what's going on here. What exactly does `63EC_Evernote.0` mean?

I checked the [Freedesktop specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), but I didn't find it particularly useful.

Comment: Thank you, Uri. I obviously expected something more sophisticated here, along the lines of Windows' reference to icons embedded in the .exe file. It never occurred to me that the installation generated a separate Ubuntu icon. (Turn you comment into an answer, and I will acknowledge it as a solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly does 63EC_Evernote.0 mean?

It may be related to the build number of Evernote, to a codename within Evernote for releases, it may just mean nothing at all and that's simply the name of the image file for the icon. Some software developers sometimes use rather cryptic names for their icons.

Imagemagick is another example of this, it's icon is called `display.img6` instead of simply calling it `imagemagick` (in this case the 6 in img6 corresponds to the version of the program).

As far as specifications is concerned you can check this question on another StackExchange site:

> - [Is there an ISO or similar recognized standard for Icons?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16616/is-there-an-iso-or-similar-recognized-standard-for-icons)